# ZF2 aka Apigility updating SQL database entry

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am attempting to update a row in a database, using the ZF2 based framework Apigility.

I'm seeing that the row exists, retrieve it's contents, and update the object..  but when I try to do `$table->update($arrayOfRowData);` I get an exception;

Documentation on how to use `Update()` is a bit sparse.. do I need to put the `where=` clause in?  Do I need to have the where clause match up with ALL of the table's primary key?(the primary key uses 3 columns)

```
try {
    // if an entry already exists, update it
    $existingRow = $this->currentEntryExists($ff_user_id, $subvalue);
    if($existingRow != false ){

        $fieldType = $this->transformer->mapField($key);
        $existingRow[$fieldType] = $subvalue['value'];
        $this->update($existingRow, $where = array('field_id' => $existingRow['field_id'], 'user_id' => $user_id, 'field_date' => $subvalue['dateTime']));
    }else{
        $fieldType = $this->transformer->mapField($key);
        $dataArray = array('user_id' => $user_id,
                           'field_date' => $subvalue['dateTime'],
                           $fieldType => $subvalue['value']);
        $result = $this->insert($dataArray);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $logger = $this->getServicesLogger();
    $logger->err($e);
    throw $e;
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
"type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
"title": "Internal Server Error",
"status": 500,
"detail": "Invalid magic property access in Zend\\Db\\TableGateway\\AbstractTableGateway::__get()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out I was trying to use a field that didn't exist in the class, and this is how Zend Framework reports it.

```
protected function getServicesLogger()
{
    if (!$this->logger) { //this field didn't exist
        $this->logger = new ApiLogger(get_class($this));
    }
    return $this->logger;
}
```